# Does IBM Watson App works outside of Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson, ibm-jazz

I've deployed Apps using IBM Watson API on Bluemix with IBM Dev Ops services and Jazz Hub Git. I was wondering if there's a possibility that we can deploy Apps from a VM directly using the IBM Watson facilities like conversation API workspace, Tone Analyzer, Text to Speech and not use IBM Bluemix and Dev Ops.

Does anyone have deployed an app outside of bluemix with IBM Watson? Is there a possibility. ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of the services in the Watson Developer Cloud are REST APIs that can be used and deployed anywhere. You do not have to use any Bluemix infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @tmarkiewicz , I see that bluemix provides VCAP services cred which should be used to make the connection to Watson. I'd want to know if without being dependent to Bluemix, would I be able to create an APP with just the calls to Watson using Python and host it my own server?

Comment: Yes - I think the confusion is that Bluemix is the overall portal to access the entire catalog of IBM SaaS services. So in order to use a Watson API, you first need to sign up for an account with Bluemix. From there, you can then sign up for and access any service offering in the Bluemix catalog, including all the Watson APIs. So there's always a dependency on going through Bluemix to get credentials, billing, etc, but you don't need to use any of the other services in conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes IBM watson service can be used outside bluemix.
Just create a instance of the service you want to use and obtain its credential. Use these credential while making a call to the service.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, are you saying it is neccessary to create an instance with bluemix and then use the credentials to make the call to Watson API. Isn't this a dependency here ?

Comment: Yes you need to first create the instance of a service and then obtain its credential.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Python example, taken from other examples I saw :)

```
from watson_developer_cloud import DiscoveryV1 

# SETUP ALL OF THE DISCOVERY API CREDENTIALS AND IDENTIFIERS; 
my_url= "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api"
my_Disc_uname= "-my-freekishglky-long-name"
my_Disc_pwd="my-random-generated-password"
my_disc_collection_id ="also from credentials after I create service"
my_disc_configuration_id = "yet-another-key"
my_disc_environment_id = "my-environment"

# FIRST  CALL TO DISCOVERY; GATHER THIS GIVES ME COOKIE AND SESSION
discovery = DiscoveryV1(
   username=my_Disc_uname,
   password=my_Disc_pwd,
   version="2016-12-01"
 )


    qopts = {
          "query": "INTERESTING STUFF",
          "count": "0",
          "filter": "yyyymmdd>20170401",
          "aggregation" : "term(docSentiment.type,count:3)"
        }

    # CALLING WATSON DISCOVERY SERVICE RIGHT HERE ...
    my_query = discovery.query(my_disc_environment_id,    my_disc_collection_id, qopts)
```

I created the service on BlueMix -- and received the credentials.  This snippet can run from my laptop and connect to the Watson Discovery service.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Does it work only if i use the VCAP services api credentials that I get from bluemix?

Comment: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/StreamingAnalytics/r_vcap_services.html#vcap_services        The credentials are from when I created the service instance.  I connect to the RESTful service ... I don't run my own personal instance in bluemix